# BS4 getting info from <br> tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have the following (simplified) html code:

```
<div class="container">
   <h1>content</h1>
   <br>
   <br>
   <div class="creator">
      <a href="example.com">user</a>
   </div>
   <br>
   <br>
   "description"
</div>
```

and how do I get the description?

Comment: The description isn't in the <br> tag -- it's in the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many methods how to select the `"description"`:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = '''<div class="container">
   <h1>content</h1>
   <br>
   <br>
   <div class="creator">
      <a href="example.com">user</a>
   </div>
   <br>
   <br>
   "description"
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

desc = soup.find('div', class_='container').contents[-1]
print(desc)
```

Prints:

```
   "description"
```

---

Or:

```
desc = soup.find('div', class_='container').find_all(text=True, recursive=False)[-1]
print(desc)
```

---

Or:

```
desc = soup.find('div', class_='container').find_all('br')[-1].find_next(text=True)
print(desc)
```